# How to show and format date with RSS2JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, rss

I can't get the date to show under each RSS item title. The dates show, but they just show at the bottom of my page. I've been trying by trial and error but I've just been stuck for a while at this point.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var content = document.getElementById('insurance-news');

function showFeed(data){
    if(data.status == 'ok'){    

        var feedlength = data.items.length;

        var output = '';

        function formatDate(myElement){
            var date = new Date(myElement);
            var months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
            var string = months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear();
            document.write(string);
        };

        for(var i=0;i<5;++i){

            output += '<p><h2><a href="' +
            data.items[i].link + '" target="_blank" >' +
            data.items[i].title + '</h2></a></p><p>' +
            formatDate(data.items[i].pubDate) + '</p>';

        }

        content.innerHTML = output;

    }

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rss2json.com/api.json?callback=showFeed&rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmix.chimpfeedr.com%2F36116-Insurance-News"></script>
```

Also, is there a way to format the date like this? October 10, 2016 14:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For format the `pubDate` of the feed as you suggested in your question, replace this line:

```
var string = months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear();
```

With this one:

```
var string = months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear() + " " + addZero(date.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(date.getMinutes());
```

I changed your code slightly and here are the results:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadNews();
});

// Load news:
function loadNews() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://rss2json.com/api.json?callback=showFeed&rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmix.chimpfeedr.com%2F36116-Insurance-News",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var feedlength = data.items.length;
            var finalHTML = "";
            var HTML_DIV = document.getElementById('divAllNews');

            // Validar que haya encontrado el div.
            if (HTML_DIV != null && HTML_DIV != undefined) {

                // Validar que la consulta traiga datos.
                if (feedlength != null && feedlength > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < feedlength; i++) {
                        finalHTML += "<div>" +
                            " <p>" + "<a href='" + data.items[i].link + "'>" + data.items[i].title + "</a>" + "</p>" +
                            " <p>" + "Date: " + formatDate(data.items[i].pubDate) + "</p>" +
                            "</div>";
                    }
                }

                // Colocar los datos.
                HTML_DIV.innerHTML = (finalHTML != "") ? finalHTML : "No results";
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('An error occurred.');
        }
    });
}

// Format date:
function formatDate(myElement) {
    var date = new Date(myElement);
    var months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    var string = months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear() + " " + addZero(date.getHours()) + ":" + addZero(date.getMinutes());
    return string;
}

// Add zero. Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp
function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divAllNews"><i>Loading news...</i></div>
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I also found that in my original code i could've just changed document.write(string); to return string;

Comment: Your code definitely helps me looks at things a different way and learn more.

Comment: @Andrew I'm glad to help.